# The import org cannot be resolved (under eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, jfreechart

I use eclipese 2018-09 (4.9.0) I'm try to use jfreechart, I added the jars in the module path(jcommon,jfreechart), I do organize import

```
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PiePlot3D;
import org.jfree.data.general.DefaultPieDataset;
import org.jfree.data.general.PieDataset;
import org.jfree.util.Rotation;
```

i get "The import org.jfree.chart cannot be resolved" for all imports and the consequential errors, what's the problem?Thanks

Comment: When using the module path instead of the classpath, what is in your `module-info.java`?

Comment: module-info.java but is empty except for "module SWTChartPie {
}" i tryed to run witout it too

Comment: Delete `module-info.java` or declare the dependencies in `module-info.java`.

Comment: I tryed with and without, I sew another error:Errore: impossibile trovare o caricare la classe principale org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart
Causato da: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart

Comment: Without knowing your Java build path and exactly which JARs it contains, I can't answer your question. I guess the new error is shown when you try to run it, right? But you first have to fix the errors shown in the _Problems_ view that prevent your code from being compiled.

Comment: Verify paths from the command line, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20%5bjfreechart%5d%20java%20cp).

Comment: @howlger you're right, i sew a warning:Build path specifies execution environment JavaSE-10. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment. but i've openjdk 11.0.1 installed

Comment: For Java 11 you have to [upgrade Eclipse to 2018-12 (4.10)](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F#Always_enable_major_upgrades). You also have to adapt the settings in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_.

Comment: other SWT application run

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to say with your last comment. Did upgrading to Eclipse 2018-12 and configure the Java JDK in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_ fix your issue? If not, extend your question by your `module-info.java` and a screenshot of _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_, tab _Libraries_.

Comment: I dont know what I must write in module-info.java, this is the screenshot https://ibb.co/tPkNbVK thanks for your time

Comment: @Andrea In this case, just delete the `module-info.java` file.

Comment: I tryed with and without module-info.java and it doesen't work in both cases

Comment: I have solved, I moved the jars in "classpath"section, now it works!